# azure billing rate card api returns noting

Tags: azure, ratecard-api

I am trying to call the Azure billing rate card api. The call is happening successfully after the authentication because the status code is OK. But though I have a vm in the corresponding resource group and subscription, always getting response as:

{"value":[]}

Same is happening in case of azure billing usage api.  I had seen one question asked for billing usage api but I have tried all the options mentioned like keep the duration for 3 months, don’t keep future date etc, yet there is no response”:

{"value":[],
nextLink:”https://….”}

Please let me know the issue could be abd because of which both rate card and usage api are not returning right data.

Thanks

Comment: Could this may be because- though I have contributor access to the resource group and the native app added has the permission to call the billing apis, I have just the “resource access” privilege in the concerned subscription? But I thought if that is the case, then probably my call to the rate card/usage apis would have failed saying access denied or unauthorized. But fortunately calls to api are going through and am getting status code as OK.

Comment: I don't think that's the reason. If you are in contributor role, the API call will work. Please share the API URL you're using. I'm guessing there's something missing there.

Comment: actually the reason was, the calling identity needs to be at least the "reader" at the subscription level. Though the identity has the contributor privilege at the azure account level.

Answer (score 0):

You were right, I had the same problem and i resolved it on giving 'reader' persmission on my servie account in my subscription .

Thx a lot !